# Configuring plugin tasks

Tags: gradle

I'm still new to Gradle and I'm struggling to understand how task configurations for plugin tasks work. Consider the `Jar` task from the Java plugin: if I overwrite the `doFirst` and `doLast` methods why does the plugin's original set of actions still occur but if I change the `description` of the `Jar` task then my new description is used? The contents of my build script are:

```
plugins{
    id 'java'
}

jar {
    description "The new description"
    doFirst {
        println "this happened first"
    }
    doLast {
        println "This happened last"
    }
}
```

I ask this more to solidify my understanding of how gradle works and not necessarily because I would like to do this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Gradle script is just a Groovy script (with some extras) that operates on the Gradle API written in Java. You can checkout the API documentation and most of your questions will be solved:

> Consider the `Jar` task from the Java plugin

Let's be pedantic on this one: There is no `Jar` task from the Java plugin, there is a task named `jar` of type `Jar`. It is very important to distinguish between task types and task instances in this context. Now let's check out the documentation of the [`Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.html) task type in Gradle. As you can see, it inherits from the type [`DefaultTask`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html). `DefaultTask` defines all those properties and methods that are common for Gradle tasks:

> `doFirst​(Closure action)` - Adds the given closure to the beginning of this task's
> action list.
> `doLast​(Closure action)` - Adds the given closure to the end of this task's action list.

As you can see, whenever you use `doFirst` or `doLast`, it will only append (or prepend) task actions to the list of existing task actions, nothing will be overriden.

Thanks to Groovy, assigning a value to the property `description` using `=` will actually call the method `setDescription`:

> `setDescription​(String description)` - Sets a description for this task.

This is a classical property setter known from the Java world. It will simply set the new value and the old value will be overridden.